# "Network autoconfiguration failed" on 16.04 minimal install

Tags: networking, 16.04, dhcp, ubuntu-minimal

History first:

Approximately a year ago, I'd successfully installed 14.04 minimal no issues.

A couple days ago I installed 16.10 minimal, but had issues completely unrelated to networking.

Yesterday I attempted an install of 16.04 minimal but continue to receive "Network autoconfiguration failed" no matter what I try.

Following that, I attempted an install of 14.04 minimal and had the same result - "Network autoconfiguration failed."

Setup and environment:

```
# lspci | grep Ethernet
```

reveals a Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller

```
# lsmod
```

shows that r8169 is up and mii is being used by it (I'm completely unfamiliar with whatever mii is, but figured I'd include it in case it was important.)

I've got DD-WRT on the router and have a static lease assigned to the MAC associated with this machine  - 192.168.1.119, as it always has been and has not changed between installations.

If I attempt to "manually" assign an IP when autoconfigure fails, the installation allows me to continue up to checking the installation mirror where it fails. It's obvious this is going to happen based on how long it hangs when it checks the link status.

EDIT 2:
Just for fun, I've also tried switching from a BIOS install to a UEFI install using 14.04 and 16.04 minimal (moved EFI folder to root of install media). But got the same results.
END EDIT.

EDIT 3:
Using the exact same media as a guest in Hyper-V autoconfigure works no problem.
END EDIT

EDIT 4:
Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop installs just fine. I also tried using 16.04 Server and did a F4 - minimal installation so I could get an offline minimal install and see if anything changed once Ubuntu was installed. Networking was still down. I checked /etc/network/interfaces, but the only interface listed was the loopback. I checked link status and enp3s0 was DOWN. After changing link to UP and adding it to interfaces, still no dice. This led me to believe it was related to the r8169 driver, but afaik it's the same driver that 16.04 Desktop uses. So, why would that be it? END EDIT

Just to add to the confusion, I popped in a PCI Intel 82541PI Gigabit that ALSO failed to get an IP when installed.

I've been searching the interwebs for possible solutions but haven't found much related to my situation

EDIT:
I guess I should add that my goal would be to get 16.04 minimal installed.

**RESOLUTION - NOT ANSWER**

I ended up installing a wireless card from another computer and connecting to a hotspot shared by my phone so I could get minimal installed. Once installed I removed the wireless card and started the machine. The wired interface was showing in a DOWN state still, so I brought it up, added a DHCP configuration for the device to /etc/network/interfaces and rebooted. Connecting through DHCP was still unsuccessful. I changed DHCP to static, added my network info to the configuration, and rebooted - connected successfully.

I did try watching packets in Wireshark from another computer, but I'm very inexperienced with it. I didn't see any ICMP or ARP traffic at all related to the MAC in question, so I'm not sure the machine was correctly requesting an address on the network. Could be wrong, though. As I said, I'm very inexperienced with reading pcaps.

Comment: what is the routers IP?

Comment: router IP - 192.168.1.1 DHCP range 192.168.1.100 - ,120

Comment: And this works with other machines?

Comment: Good question. I hadn't attempted the install on a VM yet since I'd assumed that it'd be unlikely two different distros would have the same exact issues (14.04 and 16.04). I'll give it a shot real quick and get back to ya. Shouldn't take long.

Comment: Adding an edit to original question about other things I've tried.

Comment: 16.04 minimal autoconfiguration succeeds no problem as a Guest in Hyper-V (different host obviously).

Comment: I'm wondering if something from around the network is messing with this installation somehow. No idea how that would happen though.

Comment: it seems that minimal install doesn't work while regular does? Maybe the installer is missing something, can you try 15.10?

Comment: Did you create a new external switch in Hyper-V? I hit this same issue and created a new external switch and changed the Network Adapter for the new VM. I did this while the installation was running and it picked up the network adapter change and finished the install.